# Are interesting, but specific questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted an interesting and specific question:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39129/velocity-of-glass-bottle-in-space-after-contents-are-released, which had generated 2 upvotes (therefore interesting to some members of the community)

Which was inspired by a users comment on another post, who thought the above question was interesting:
[If I take a bottle of air into space, and open it, where does it go?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23588/if-i-take-a-bottle-of-air-into-space-and-open-it-where-does-it-go?rq=1)

Unfortunately the question was closed as being too specific.  So are questions that are specific in nature, but illustrate interesting concepts off-topic on this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions which instruct people to solve a problem without showing any work are not appropriate as per our [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714). That's why your question was closed. I used the "too localized" close reason out of habit, but "off topic" would apply equally well.

You could probably turn your question into something appropriate by going on to say something like "I tried to solve this by doing XXX then YYY, but after that I got stuck because I don't see any way to calculate ZZZ from YYY. Is it possible to do this, and how?" That makes it a conceptual question.

Comment: Thanks, your link to the Homework policy was helpful.  I now realize that homework as defined here, isn't the same as the conventional meaning of the term and has cleared up some confusion.